# How to get a list of Metric Alerts from Azure

Tags: azure, terraform

Im building some alerts using Terraform and am doing one for Load Balancer. I usually go to the portal and look at the alert name via the metrics option. From there i get the alert name and use it in terraform. However for Load Balance there is a metric called "Health Probe Status", but when I use this in terraform it complains "BadRequest" Message="Couldn't find a metric named Health Probe Status."

All the other alerts i create are ok? How do I find the Health Probe Status alert name for terraform ?

Comment: think I found it myself, in the portal go to the resource you want to monitor > select Metrics > Select a Metric from the dropdown box, hover the mouse over the metric and you will see a MetricID pop up

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [itye1970](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5272061/itye1970). Adding your comment as answer to help other community users.

> In the portal go to the resource you want to monitor --> select Metrics --> Select a Metric from the dropdown box, hover the mouse over the metric and you will see a MetricID pop up